# Fullcalendar Engine - How to get notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, notifications, fullcalendar

In Rails 4.1.4, I am using `gem 'fullcalendar_engine'` for calendar events. Referred through https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine

Demo application has been implemented as same as https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine-demo-app

How can I get notifications as per the events?

Comment: it depends when you want to get the events notifications...on creation/deletion/updation.So you can use an observer with callbacks such as on_create/on_update/on_save....